# Finding the exact failing field with ID in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, lucene.net

I have a structured JSON data in the following form:

```
field1:{
  "id" : "123",
  "field2" : [
    {
     "id" : "345",
     "type" : "ABC"
    },
    {
     "id" : "456",
     "type" : "XYZ"
    },
   ]
}
```

I'm converting this JSON into lucene document as

```
field1.id : 123
field1.field2.id : 345
field1.field2.type: ABC 
field1.field2.id : 456
field1.field2.type: XYZ
```

I've a query which states that type should be equal to ABC i.e `+field1.field2.type: ABC`. I need to find the exact id for the field failing, in this case.. 123->345. How can I achieve that ?

I cannot store the id in the field like `field1.123.field2.456.type` - it is not possible. Is there any possible way to do with SortedSetDocValuesField or FeatureField. Anything that lucene provides to store the id attached with the value for a specific field.

Answer (score 0):

For me, field2 is an array of objects so the right conversion would be ( or an equivalent) :

```
field1.id : 123
field1.field2[0].id : 345
field1.field2[0].type: ABC 
field1.field2[1].id : 456
field1.field2[1].type: XYZ
```

Can you add your code so we can analyse better please

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can generate the lucene document in the format as mentioned above. There could be multiple array of objects In the json.  
I need to create a lucene query something like "-field1.field2[*].type : ABC".  The query would fail if field2.type is not equal to ABC and I need to get the id (i.e 456) for that. Is it possible to create a wildcard query over a fieldName in lucene ?

Answer (score 0):

not sure that i get it (not enough information).
As i see you can add combined uid:
field2_path: 123_345  (so each sub object in array can contains part of parent document id and also own id). plus "_" deliminator can give yuo possibility to restore document id.

another variant:
field2_id:  can be multiple field value, so it can contains both "parent id" and "own id". to know which id is related to which level of structure - prefix can be added. So lucene document should contains two fields with same name:  field2_id = 0_123   field2_id = 1_345

as i said it is not well known - structure of document; search query (result to achieve

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already tried this. I need to create a lucene query something like "-field1.field2[*].type : ABC". The query would fail if field2.type is not equal to ABC and I need to get the id (i.e 456) for that. Is it possible to create a wildcard query over a fieldName in lucene ?

Comment: There is possibility to use MultyFieldQuery - so you have to specify all posible fields and token that you are gonig to search in them.
 it is an equivalent to few sub queries with "or" between them. Somethnig like:
    (field1.field21.type = ABC or  field1.field22.type = ABC  or  field1.field23.type = ABC) and 
((field1.field21.id = 456 or  field1.field22.id = 456 or  field1.field23.id = 456)

as you can see this solution is not good enough, because

Comment: And solution  is on "indexing" side- look like you have to prepared "combined field value" - 3rd field:  field1.field2.id_and_type = ABC__456
so during search you can construct exact query:
    field1.field2.id_and_type = {type}*__{id}*

Comment: it is hard to explain in comment - i have rich limits and can't edit anymore my first answer.  and aswer that i see two varinats:     a) when you construct multiple fields query 2 time (one fore type fields one for id's)   b) yuo have to reconstruct index - to index id and type of field2 as one value, so during search stage - yuo can search by combination of them (it is in my comment above)